# Visio 2003: UML class diagrams - abstract class

Tags: visio, uml

I am trying to create UML diagrams but can not mark a class as Abstract. Please help.

Comment: I don't see why this has the C# tag attached.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the class, either in a static structure diagram, or in the Model Explorer.
Activate the "Properties" context menu item to bring up the properties dialog for that class.

On the first tab, check the "IsAbstract" checkbox.

The class will now be displayed in italics.