# How to set a class to abstract using Microsoft Visio

Tags: uml, visio, class-diagram

I'm using Microsoft Visio to draw my UML Diagrams.

More specifically the "UML Class" package as shown below

[image: Here's a screenshot link]

I want to define my class as *`Abstract`* and I don't find any "Properties tab" or somth to manage any class options.

Is there any way to achieve this another way than simply set the class name as Italic in the text format option ?

**EDIT**

[The solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712340/visio-2003-uml-class-diagrams-abstract-class) doesn't seem to fit with newer version of Visio as long as i can't find a "Properties" tab.

Comment: Adding a screenshot might help giving a better answer (i.e. specific to your UML package used with Visio).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visio 2003: UML class diagrams - abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712340/visio-2003-uml-class-diagrams-abstract-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Visio is not the greatest tool to create UML models. Of course it lets you draw nice diagrams, especially with the right packages, but what you get is not really related to each other.

Getting back to your question, there are many different possibilities depending on specific UML package you use. If you don't have anything special and you can't find some "Abstract" or IsAbstract" property of the class, you can always just change the text format to Italic.

Comment: I was previously using VisualParadigm. Should I get back on it ? Or is there a nicer program to draw UML class diagrams ?

Comment: There is a choice of applications, and Visual Paradigm is one of far better options than Visio. If you want something lighter you may consider StarUML or Modelio. Use Google to see what are the options and check which fits you best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your usefull answers

Answer (score 1):

All the "smarts" (for want of a better name) have been removed from the UML shapes in the later versions of Visio, 2013 onwards as far as I know. There is a "Properties" attribute to the Class shape in Visio 2010 but not in Visio 2016. The shapes are now just plain and simple.